# How to apply style to a paragraph with PHP

Tags: php, css, css-tables

I would like to style a paragraph using PHP in a newsletter built in tables. (white color, padding etc...)
But it's not working.
The paragraph is in the variable $result.

Here is the td cell where I'm displaying a title and the paragraph I'm struggling with :

```
<td class="resize-main-article" width="49%" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#000000">
    <a class="whitecolor" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;" href="<?php echo get_post_permalink($post->ID); ?>" target="_blank">
        <p style="color:#ffffff; font-size: 22px; margin-top: 10px; padding: 10px; font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif; margin: 0;" width="100%">
            <span style="color: #ed2939;"> 
                <?php echo get_field('overtitle', $post->ID); ?> / 
            </span>
            <?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>
        </p>

<?php 
$post_content = $post->post_content;
$post_content = apply_filters('the_content', $post_content);
if (preg_match('%^(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)$%im', $post_content, $regs)) {
   $result = $regs[1];
} else {
   $result = "";
}
echo "<p style='color:#ffffff; font-size: 14px; padding: 10px; margin: 0;' width='100%'>" . $result . "</p>";
?>

    </a>
</td>
```

[Here is what I get (so no stylisation applied...)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFOCN.png)

[Here is the HTML output I get, which gets me a bit confused...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iIU03.png)

Thank you a lot in advance !

Comment: Your echo already has CSS style attributes set....

Comment: Isn't that `<p>` element you're wrapping it in doing exactly that?  What is the resulting HTML being output by that `echo` and how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: Is `$result` the *contents* of the paragraph, or the contents *and* the surrounding paragraph tags?

Comment: Hi Martin, yes, this is the style I actually want to apply to  $result. It is written inline because I'm building a newsletter in tables.

Comment: Hi jo8691, I think that $result also includes the tags...

Comment: Hi David, what I expect is to apply a white color, and other different things to the first paragraph.

Comment: @Skaradron: Have you examined the actual HTML output yet?  As well as any other CSS styling that might be applied to that element?  A picture of what your webpage looks like is not the same thing as debugging.  Look at the page source.

Comment: @David, thank you for the precision, I'm starting here... :s I updated my question in order to be more precise, hope it is more clear and thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

As your image shows, your rendered code results in one paragraph being nested inside another, e.g.

```
<p>
  <p>...</p>
</p>
```

which is invalid HTML. Most browsers will attempt to correct this and un-nest them, which would result in

```
<p></p>
<p>...</p>
```

with the outer `<p>` being rendered before the inner one, so your styled outer `<p>` would be empty and the styling not applied to the inner `<p>`.

Modify your `$result` string containing the paragraph of text so it doesn't have the outer `<p>` and apply your styling via a stylesheet or by manipulating the contents of `$result`, but do not wrap `$result` in another paragraph as you are doing.

Comment: Thank you a lot ! I'm starting to get it. I sadly can't use stylesheet as it isn't recommended due to compatibility issues for newsletters... But I understand more my nesting problems. Thank you ☺️

Comment: @Skaradron Then you'll need to manipulate the string in `$result` to style it